# Yii dependant dropDownList

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

I need to create to dependant dropDownLists with yii. Thus, I create a view and an action in controller like this :

**The view**

```
<?php
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'id_structure');
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'id_structure', GxHtml::listDataEx(StructureInformation::model()->findAllAttributes()), 
array('ajax' => array('type' => 'POST', 
    'url' => CController::createUrl('InfoComplementAAjouter/fillTypeList'), 
    'update' => '#typeDonnee', 
    'data' => array('id_structure' => 'js:this.value'))
));
echo $form->error($model, 'id_structure');
echo '</div>';
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'type');
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'type', array(), array('prompt' => 'Sélectionner', 'id' => 'typeDonnee'));
echo $form->error($model, 'type');
echo '<div>';
?>
```

Now the **action** in the Controller `InfoComplementAAjouterController` :

```
public function actionFillTypeList(){

        $id_struct = $_POST['InfoComplementAAjouter']['id_structure']; //I get the selected value
        $taille = StructureInformation::model()->find('id = ' . (int)$id_struct)->taille; //and then pass it to the StructureInformation model to obtain the attribute taille

        //I create two arrays which content will be the options of my dropDownList. 
        $un = array('text'=> 'Texte', 'radio' => 'Bouton radio', 'dropDownList' => 'Liste déroulante');
        $plusieurs = array( 'checkboxlist' => 'Choix multiple',);
        //If $taille == 1, I display the contents of $un; if $taille > 1, the content of $plusieurs will be displayed.
        if($taille == 1){
            foreach ($un AS $value => $name){
                $opt = array();
                $opt['value'] = $value;

                echo CHtml::tag('option', $opt, CHtml::encode($name), true);
            }
        }
       if($taille > 1){
            foreach ($plusieurs AS $value => $name){
                $opt = array();
                $opt['value'] = $value;

                echo CHtml::tag('option', $opt, CHtml::encode($name), true);
            }
        }
        die;
    }
```

I remark that the action is not executed. I can not understand why.
Can somebody help me to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a typo:

```
'upedate' => '#typeDonnee',
```

should be `'update'`

try with fixing it first

**Edit:**

you have more small errors/typos

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'id_structure', GxHtml::listDataEx(StructureInformation::model()->findAllAttributes(), 
array('ajax' => array('type' => 'POST', 
    'url' => CController::createUrl('InfoComplementAAjouter/fillTypeList'), 
    'update' => '#typeDonnee', 
    'data' => array('id_structure' => 'js:this.value'))
));
```

here you need to close parentheses

=====================================================

```
StructureInformation::model()->findAllAttributes()
```

there is no `findAllAttributes()` method in `CActiveRecord`
maybe you wanted to use `findAllByAttributes()`, but then you would want to pass some attributes. If this is your custom method then you should explain how it works, or paste a code

**Edit 2:**

```
$_POST['InfoComplementAAjouter']['id_structure']
```

Try to access post like this:

```
$_POST['id_structure']
```

I think you send post in that structure

It's not that easy for me to duplicate your situation, so I'm kinda shooting in the dark

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't fix it. I must edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Ok, ok ! When writing the post, I made some mistakes, as I don't copy and paste.

Comment: `findAllAttributes()` is a method of `GxActiveRecord`, as I'am using the Gii extension to generate my models, controllers and views.

Comment: No, any error. The second dropDownList remains empty, even if another value is selected in the first one.